# Will covering ring on male 1/4 TRS jack with tape work?

Tags: audio, cables

I plan to connect balanced TRS output with unbalanced TS  input and I wonder if instead of cutting the cable and leaving ring floating I could just cover the male jack itself (the ring part that goes to the unbalanced input) with insulation tape. My guess is it should prevent the signal from the ring connect with the sleeve of the unbalanced, TS input.

Comment: Apart from the mechanical difficulty of plugging in the jack without removing the tape, this is unanswerable without details of the internal circuit implementation of the devices.  Things that would work in one case may vary well damage your gear or produce overwhelming mains hum in another.  Questions about the *usage* of products which do not have engineering documentation are off topic here.

Comment: Devices I'm connecting are tascam us2x2 audio interface and guitar pedal Behringer super fuzz. Their documentations doesn't provide information about such connections.

Comment: It's precisely the lack of documentation which makes *usage* questions off topic

Answer (score 4):

Both are terrible "solution" in that they are no *solutions* at all.

Conversion from balanced to unbalanced isn't done by isolating conductors, since the "other" side of the balanced signal isn't at a defined potential. That's the whole point of balanced signalling. The potential *difference* between the two balanced conductors is driven by an output driver, but if you make one float and connect the other, then chances are that he floating one is the one that will be driven, whereas the one that you connect will be more or less at a fixed potential relative to the receiver. "More or less", because capacitive effects will probably make this sound like a high-pass signal.

Instead, properly convert your balanced output to an unbalanced one: A signal transformer would do that.

In a pinch, connecting one of the balanced lines to ground and using the other would *probably* work, too, but only if the introduced offset is in the range of what the output can drive.

Comment: Output of my audio interface says that balanced line out so yes it's balanced trs. I heard opinions that sometimes you want to leave ring floating and sometimes you want to connect it to sleeve but it depends on the connection and in my case it should be ring left floating. It's all a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cutting anything or sticking tape on things, just build yourself a short adapter cable from an inline TRS jack and a TS plug. Then, you can explicitly either wire the R to S or leave it open, as appropriate for your specific signal source. You could even include a small SPST switch that allows you to select either option.

In an ideal world, you'll make sure that both T and R are terminated with [equal impedances](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/231297/11683) to S — in which case, the switch becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Do you mean inline TRS jack like the REAN-NYS2203P ? I wonder if disassembling it would be as easy as just cutting through TRS male cable, then TS male cable and connecting them as I want.